# Can't access Neo4j community version in the browser (installed on a Linux virtual machine in Azure)

Tags: azure, neo4j, azure-virtual-machine

I tried to install Neo4j community edition on a VM in Azure, I can't access it in the browser.

I did this:

1. Created a virtual machine in Azure on which you can host a Neo4j community version server
   I choose Linux (Ubuntu 18.04) virtual machine in Azure
2. Connect to the virtual machine throught Azure CLI and start installing
3. Installed Java 11 throught Azure CLI
4. Installed the latest Neo4j community version throught Azure CLI
5. Setted up Neo4j to be accessible over the internet: sudo vim /etc/neo4j/neo4j.conf
6. Add/edit the following lines to the config file:

   dbms.connector.bolt.enabled=true
   dbms.connector.bolt.listen_address=0.0.0.0:7687
   dbms.connector.http.enabled=true
   dbms.connector.http.listen_address=0.0.0.0:7474
7. To access port 7474 from outside the Linux machine, I added it to the inbound port rules for the virtual machine (but I'm not sure if I did it wright)

[image]

Inbound security rules:

[image]

8. I tried to access to Neo4j in the browser with: http://<ip_adress_of_vm>:7474

But 8) doesn't work: ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED.
I don't know if it is the best method to install Neo4j community version in a Linux virtual machine.

What do I have to change to succeed in opening this in the browser ? Maybe I did bad 7) ?

Comment: Can you share the screenshot of the inbound rules? I need to know what rules you have created. And do you access the Neo4j inside the VM?

Comment: Hello @CharlesXu, I just founded my mistake. I have forgotten to add the 7474 & 7687 in inbound rules. Thank you for your time.

Comment: Well, I will add an answer and if you do not mind, please accept it.

Comment: Hello @CharlesXu I'm going to share the screenshot off the inbound rules because I still have a problem with the VM. 
Sorry I did not understand 'And do you access the Neo4j inside the VM?'
You will see an update of the post with the screenshot.

Comment: Access the Neo4j inside the VM is to test if the Neo4j works fine without the NSG rules.

Comment: Yes with Putty I can ssh the VM. I tested it with the command: sudo systemctl status neo4j.service.
And the result is: "Loaded: enabled, Active: active (running)"

Comment: Do you test it with the command `curl HTTP://localhost:7474`?

Comment: I tested it when I installed the VM and it was working. Do I have to try now ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/224404/discussion-between-charles-xu-and-ljrb).

Answer (score 1):

According to the messages you provided, the problem is that you do not add the Inbound rules for ports 7474 and 7687 to allow the traffic.

Comment: I still have a problem with the VM, I'm going to update the post with a screenshot of the inbound rules. It takes time for the page to have neo4j browser when I try to access to Neo4j in the browser with: http://<ip_adress_of_vm>:7474. I have to refresh 3 times and after this it is working.

Comment: @LJRB If it is accessible outside, then there is no other problem. If you try to access it immediately when you add the rules for the ports? Maybe it needs time to make the rules work.